# How to properly assign values to string in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

**I am running a snippet code in kotlin:**

```
if(element.regStatus!!.code.equals(Keys.CODE_REGISTERED,true)){

                var nameSize: Int? = element.paxInformation!!.size

                element.paxInformation!!.forEachIndexed { _, paxInfo ->

                    var displayName: String? =""
                    if(paxInfo.isIsPrimaryRegistrant){
                        displayName = "Dev"
                    }

                    if(nameSize!! >1){
                        displayName = displayName +" "+ "+" + nameSize
                    }

                    listData!!.add(CustomEventSummaryPpl(displayName,paxInfo.mobile))
                }
            }
```

---

**In the code:**

```
var displayName: String? =""
                        if(paxInfo.isIsPrimaryRegistrant){
                            displayName = "Dev"
                        }
```

---

```
displayName = "Dev"
```

Always has `displayName` as `null`

**How to properly assign values to string ?**

Comment: probably unrelated to the issue (and if it fixed the problem, it would be weird anyway), but you could clear some nullable types a little bit. Specifically the `displayName`, you're assigning `""` upon creation, is inside of a `forEachIndexed` scope (in which you're skipping the `index`, so you could transform it to `forEach`) and only leaving it in the `CustomEventSummaryPpl` constructor, at which point it being nullable or not is no longer relevant. Also the `Int?` could be moved to `Int`, and you no longer need to enforce it to be non null at `nameSize!!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is perfect and the problem is with your if condition. You can write a else condition and store a value like this.

```
if(paxInfo.isIsPrimaryRegistrant){
            displayName = "Dev"
        }else{
            displayName = "empty"
        }
```

Comment: there's an even more "kotlin-ish" way to write it: `var displayName = if(paxInfo.isIsPrimaryRegistrant) "Dev" else ""`